# how to remove last occurance of underscore in string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains many underscores followed by words ex: "`Field_4_txtbox`" I need to find the last underscore in the string and remove everything following it(including the "_"), so it would return to me "`Field_4`" but I need this to work for different length ending strings. So I can't just trim a fixed length.

I know I can do an If statement that checks for certain endings like

```
if(strstr($key,'chkbox')) {
    $string= rtrim($key, '_chkbox');
}
```

but I would like to do this in one go with a regex pattern, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The matching regex would be:

```
/_[^_]*$/
```

Just replace that with '':

```
preg_replace( '/_[^_]*$/', '', your_string );
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to use an extremly costly regex, a simple **[`strrpos()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)** would do the job:

```
$string=substr($key,0,strrpos($key,"_"));
```

> **strrpos** — Find the position of the *last* occurrence of a substring in a string

Comment: I think this would find the first occurrence of an underscore.

Comment: @Robbert - i am using strrpos, not strpos (mind the extra r), which searches reverse.

Comment: The main point is to avoid the extremly costly regex for a cheap string reverse search, that  hits afte just a few comparations.

Comment: @Eugen clever use of strrpos +1

Comment: @EugenRieck I edited your answer to make it more clear that you're using `strrpos()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use [`explode()`](http://uk.php.net/explode):

```
$string = 'Field_4_txtbox';
$temp = explode('_', strrev($string), 2);
$string = strrev($temp[1]);
echo $string;
```

As of PHP 5.4+

```
$string = 'Field_4_txtbox';
$string = strrev(explode('_', strrev($string), 2)[1]);
echo $string;
```

Comment: is this faster then preg_replace?

Comment: @Undermine2k I don't know, but what I do know is that we're talking about micro-optimisation. So you should better go for "readable code". Personally I think that `preg_replace()` is more readable, I just thought of providing another solution :)